# Out-of-sample forecasting in F#

Tags: r, f#

I am a novice in F# and would like to run an out-of-sample OLS forecast. I have a frame that looks similar to the following. I would like to estimate parameters using the first 3 data points then forecast the last data point.

```ml
let dfff= 
[ "year" => series [ 1 => 1990.0; 2 => 1991.00; 3 => 1992.0;  4 => 1993.0]
"gold"  => series [ 1 => 10.0; 2 => 10.00; 3 => 15.0; 4 => 20.0] 
"silver"  => series [ 1 => 20.0; 2 => 30.00; 3 => 45.0; 4 => 55.0] ] 
|> frame
|> Frame.indexColsWith ["one"; "two"; "three"]

let dfff2 = dfff |> Frame.filterRows (fun k row -> row?one <= 1992.0 )
let mygold = [| for i in dfff2.GetColumn<float>("two").Values -> i |] 
let mysilver = [| for i in dfff2.GetColumn<float>("three").Values -> i |] 

let myparam =
namedParams [
    "a", box mygold;
    "b", box mysilver;
] |> R.data_frame

let myresult = R.lm(formula = "a~b", data = myparam) 
R.summary(myresult)
let mycoefs = R.coef(R.summary(myresult))
let residuals = myresult.AsList().["residuals"].AsNumeric()
let dfff3 = dfff |> Frame.filterRows (fun k row -> row?one == 1993.0 )
```

Could anybody help me out how to complete the code? I would like to retrieve the beta and alpha coefficients and estimate the out of sample forecast.This line will not work:

```
let beta=mycoefs.[1,1]
let predict=[| for i in dfff3 -> fun float i*beta |]
```

Comment: It's quite a lot of questions. I would have advised you to choose one primary or to try to find help in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Comment: Are you using the R type provider (http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider) or are you writing the code from scratch in F#? I'm sure people would be happy to answer if you provided a bit more details (and a piece of code that you tried to write, but that didn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning up your sample code to be more readable:

```ml
let dfff= 
    [ "year" => series [ 1 => 1990.0; 2 => 1991.00; 3 => 1992.0;  4 => 1993.0]
      "gold"  => series [ 1 => 10.0; 2 => 10.00; 3 => 15.0; 4 => 20.0] 
      "silver"  => series [ 1 => 20.0; 2 => 30.00; 3 => 45.0; 4 => 55.0] ] 
    |> frame

let dfff2 = dfff |> Frame.filterRows (fun k row -> row?year <= 1992.0 )
let dfff3 = dfff |> Frame.filterRows (fun k row -> row?year = 1993.0 )

let myresult = R.lm(formula = "gold~silver", data = dfff2) 
R.summary(myresult)
let mycoefs = R.coef(R.summary(myresult))
```

You could predict the final observation a couple ways:

```ml
R.predict_lm(myresult, dfff3)
/// val it : SymbolicExpression =        4 
/// 16.57895
```

Or

```ml
let betas = mycoefs.AsNumericMatrix().[0..1,0]
betas.[0] + (dfff3.["silver"].Values |> Array.ofSeq).[0] * betas.[1]

/// val it : float = 16.57894737
```

Your original question mentioned a moving window. You could more generally do something like below, which has an expanding window for out of sample forecasts. I have also utilized year as the index because it is a time series.

```ml
open RProvider
open RDotNet
open RProvider.``base``
open RProvider.stats
open System
open Deedle

let years = [|1990 .. 2010|]
let rand = System.Random()
let gold = [ for i in years do yield rand.NextDouble()]
let silver = [ for i in gold do yield 2.0 * i + rand.NextDouble()]

let x = Frame.ofColumns["gold"  => Series(years, gold);
                        "silver" => Series(years, silver) ]

let listOfWindows = 
    [for year in years.[2..] do 
     yield x |> Frame.filterRows (fun key row -> key <= year)]

listOfWindows |> List.map (fun x -> 
    let yearToPredict = x.RowKeys |> Seq.max
    let train = 
        x |> Frame.filterRows (fun year _ -> year < yearToPredict)
    let test = 
        x |> Frame.filterRows (fun year _ -> year = yearToPredict)
    let mdl = R.lm("silver~gold", train)
    let predicted = R.predict_lm(mdl, test).AsNumeric().[0]
    let actual = test.["silver"].[yearToPredict]
    yearToPredict, predicted, actual
    )

/// val it : (int * float * float) list =
///  [(1987, 2.229193258, 1.281468206); (1988, 1.111561003, 1.248677743);
///   (1989, 1.039488768, 0.7363931172); (1990, 1.680597973, 1.808993845);
///   (1991, 1.943243437, 2.092237694); (1992, 2.555973809, 2.00253973);...
///
```

Comment: I think you might not need `R.as_data_frame` in the call `dfff3 |> R.as_data_frame`, because R provider does the conversion automatically...